# Cannot override after_inactive_sign_up_path_for on Devise RegistrationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise with Invitable and Confirmable.

When signin up, I would like to redirect the user to a confirm page, instead of showing the flash message.

I have in my route.rb setup the following:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    :confirmations => 'confirmations',
    :registrations => 'registrations'
}
```

And my RegistrationsController (/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb) is:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    protected

    def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        "http://google.com"
    end
end
```

But no matter what I try, `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` is not being called, and it just continues with the flash message.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
:registrations => 'registrations'
```

to

```
:registrations => "users/registrations"
```

Also, you are overriding the inactive signup, if you want to redirect after a successful signup then you should override `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)`

Comment: I trial to change the routing but it didn't work. I don't want to override after_inactive_sign_up_path_for since, the user has to confirm the account, and I would like to display a confirm page instead of just a flash notification.

Comment: Do you want to redirect the user after a successful sign up or after a non-successful signup?

Comment: I want to redirect on signup, but before account is confirmed.